# How to index or subset a specific value from an output table

Tags: r, indexing, subset

I am a relative beginner in R, which I use for social science related data analysis, and I have a question. I am trying to run a confirmatory factor analysis on an example data set and I still learning the ins and outs of subsetting and indexing. I feel this is one of the most important skills to learn for my profession yet sometimes I have trouble with it during specific coding situations.

If I run a statistical analysis and get my summary results in the console panel, say I have a large correlation matrix that I am navigating, yet I want to find specific values in the correlation matrix that meet a cutoff criteria without having to look through the matrix on my own, how do I do that? Here is my current code and output:

So this code here

```
install.packages("lavaan")
library(lavaan)

#Select rows 8-16 from dataset and apply to new df
Holzinger1 <- HolzingerSwineford1939[ ,8:16]

#Specify model from the dataset
HS.model <- 'visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
             verbal =~ x4 + x5 + x6
             speed =~ x7 + x8 + x9'
fit <- cfa(HS.model, Holzinger1, std.lv = TRUE, missing= "fiml")
summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE, standardized=TRUE)
residuals <- residuals(fit, type = "cor")
```

Led to this residuals matrix in the output

```
> residuals
$type
[1] "cor.bollen"

$cov
       x1     x2     x3     x4     x5     x6     x7     x8     x9
 x1  0.000                                                        
 x2 -0.030  0.000                                                 
 x3 -0.008  0.094  0.000                                          
 x4  0.071 -0.012 -0.068  0.000                                   
 x5 -0.009 -0.027 -0.151  0.005  0.000                            
 x6  0.060  0.030 -0.026 -0.009  0.003  0.000                     
 x7 -0.140 -0.189 -0.084  0.037 -0.036 -0.014  0.000              
 x8 -0.039 -0.052 -0.012 -0.067 -0.036 -0.022  0.075  0.000       
 x9  0.149  0.073  0.147  0.048  0.067  0.056 -0.038 -0.032  0.000

 $mean
 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 
  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 `
```

I tried using something along these lines to find the values in the $cov part that matched the cutoff value

Because I know you can index data frames that way however I get an error

```
> residuals$cov[residuals$cov > abs(1), residuals$cov > abs(1)]
Error in residuals$cov[residuals$cov > abs(1), residuals$cov > abs(1)] : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long`
```

Probably because my code is completely wrong. As you can see earlier in my code I did something similar to what I want by selecting columns 8:16 from the df HolzingerSwineford1939.

So what type of code can I utilize to search for and pull values from a summary or analysis results output table or matrix that meet the cutoff/ logical criteria I specify? Is there even any code at all that will do that or do I just have to look myself?

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Editing to include solution for above data, please replace 0.05 with 1 in the first line after verifying it works. There are no elements in the data > 1 to test with.

```
## Gives position by row/columns

position <- which(abs(residuals$cov) > 0.05, arr.ind = T)
position

## Gives Numeric Values

residuals$cov[position]

### Create data frame (if needed)
names <- rownames(position) # find row names from qualifying row/col
position_df <- as.data.frame(position) # convert matrix to df
position_df$value <- residuals$cov[position] # put values into df
position_df$var <- names # add names into df
position_df <- position_df[!duplicated(position_df$var),] 
## This line removes duplicated variable values, note use of comma in brackets
position_df
```

You should use `dput()` to provide sample data in order for people to help, that way we can test the code. Also see [Hadley Wickham - Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) it's free and has a good section on indexing.

I had to re-read this not realizing you needed a matrix - you can find the position using arr.ind = T inside a which statement, and the position can then be used to extract values, or you can use position[1](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/) to find rownames. They can be put in a data frame from there if that is what you need.

```
Test <- matrix(c(1,1,3,5,6,7, 1, 1), nrow=4)
rownames(Test) <- c("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
position <- which(Test ==7, arr.ind = T)
Test[position]
rownames(Test)[position[1]]
together <- data.frame(Value = Test[position], Name=rownames(Test)[position[1]])
```

Here is the which function on a vector - this will also work to extract values from a df$matrix (using $ extractor) except you only get numbers and not rownames, but if you just need values this will work fine.

```
Test <- c(1,1,3,5,6)
Test[which(Test > abs(1) & Test > abs(3))]
```

This will also work:

```
Test[Test > 3 | Test > 5]
```

by the way (& is for and and | is for 'or' in joining conditions).

Comment: I apologize but I really didn't understand much of this. As I said I am a beginner and I think you explained it thinking maybe I was more of an intermediate user or something.

How can I post the data set so that you can show me the code that would be specific for the example? Again, I need data values that are greater than 1 from the matrix or table whatever you call it residuals$cov

Comment: If you use the dput function, dput(df) to post some of the data structure and explain the output you are looking for it would be easier to assist. For example, let us know if you just want the numbers over abs(1) or if you want numbers and rownames. But basically, a matrix has a row and column so you can use which(matrix > abs(1), arr.ind = T) to find the position in terms of row/column. That position can also be used inside square brackets to return the value e.g. matrix[which(matrix > abs(1), arr.ind = T)]

Comment: Also - you can paste the above code into R studio to see how it works, that why the first lines create a matrix and vector called "Test" so you can experiment with the code on your own system.

Comment: I found out you can download the MBESS package and then use data(HolzingerSwineford1939) to get the dataframe I used. Then just copy and paste my code. Again looking for a way to simply have R tell me the row and column where the value inside the $cov matrix is > abs(1)

Comment: If you only know code where it tells me the values and not the row or column that's fine it's better than nothing but if you can do it so R tells you the row and column name where the data values are > |1| that would be best. I am trying to fit your code to my purposes but it's just not working lol. I can index a regular dataframe just fine but I'm having issues with these output data types.

Comment: I edited an answer above - there is nothing +/- 1 so I used 0.05 to test things, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: OK, where did you edit an answer and where is there code for testing .05? Also is it possible to have a logical or boolean index where I ask R if there are values greater than or equal to abs(1) and it returns a TRUE or a FALSE and then if true I can run the code that would select those values that are > abs(1)

Comment: Above in the original answer - this line: `position <- which(abs(residuals$cov) > 0.05, arr.ind = T)` That is the line that pulls the matrix index position, change it to > 1 and it will find values > 1. The code above also looks up the values and will put them into a data table if needed.